# How to upload a file through the js-doc-upload button, using Selenium WD + Java + JUnit?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, junit, automated-tests

I want to upload a file and code of upload button is like:

```
<button class="panel-box-header__controls-bttn bttn-icon js-doc-upload" type="button">
            <svg class="icon icon-clip">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-clip"></use>
            </svg>
        </button>
```

Method `driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendKeys("path of the file which u want to upload");` doesn't work here

Method Robot also doesn't work:

```js
    public void upload() throws Exception {
        uploadButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
//File Need to be imported
        File file = new File("/Users/admin/Desktop/test_image.jpg");
        StringSelection stringSelection= new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());
//Copy to clipboard
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
        Robot robot = new Robot();
// Cmd + Tab is needed since it launches a Java app and the browser looses focus
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(500);
//Open Goto window
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
//Paste the clipboard value
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
//Press Enter key to close the Goto window and Upload window
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(500);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }
```

When I use the Robot method as in the example above, there is a click on the upload button, then a window with files opens and nothing happens anymore, the specified file isn't upload.

Maybe someone has a solution to this problem? Using the Robot method or any other options

Answer (score 1):

You can't `.sendKeys()` to a button or svg element. Neither are designed to accept input.

The `.sendKeys()` method works when the site uses a standard `<input type="file />` input for upload.

You'll need to use Robot or some other method to click on the button and select the file for upload.

Comment: yes, I understand that I can't use `.sendKeys()`, I just click on upload button (via xpath) and after frame with files is opened I don't know which method I can use to upload a file. I've seen some examples which using Robot method, but anyway it does't help with this uploader. Well, I'll search for more options anyway, thanks for answer